# How to login to Microservices ui app using jhipster

Tags: jhipster, microservices

I am creating a `jhipster` application using microservices. I have created JHipster Registry, UAAserver, 2 microservices calling 2 Ui apps on 2 different url. Have added entities in 2 UI apps, using Mongodb for database. Have run all the above JHipster Registry, UAAserver, 2 microservices, 2 Uiapp's and i am able to see all running in Jhipster registry and tables being created in Mongodb but when i try to login to Uiapp1 or UiApp2 its throwing

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.0.10:9999/login. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
>   Origin 'http://192.168.0.10:8084' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Neither i am able to login to http://192.168.0.10:9999/login which is my UAAServer.

Can someone please help me to what configuration or authentication needs to be set for the same.

Comment: Trying to build and run application through : https://jhipster.github.io/microservices-architecture/ architecture

Comment: There's a bug in jhipster uaa due to a spring boot 1.5.1 change,  fix https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/5313 Wait for JHipster 4.0.7 or apply the fix by yourself.

Comment: Also make sure you have enabled cors in your application*.yml files.

Answer (score 2):

as Gael told, this happens due to a bug in 4.0.6, where we switched to spring boot 1.5.1

this changed the filter order. Just add

```
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      filter-order: 3
```

to application.yml, or wait for the next release with a fix to that error

Comment: thanks david :added changes in application.yml
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      filter-order: 3

   Now i able to log in to both uiappone and uiapptwo
But only able to save in uiapptwo which has one entity
and not in uiapptwo which has 2 entities.   Its showing "Key bytes can only be specified for HMAC signatures. Please specify a PublicKey or PrivateKey instance." and when we land on that entity or try to save a record it throws :" Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"  in both SEND and GET methods related to cacheBuster

Comment: this sounds to a specific problem to your code base